# Using jMeter to test submitting a query and getting its results

Tags: post, jmeter

I am developing a webpage that allow the user to submit a query then get set of results and I want to test if my webpage can be used by concrete 500 users, so I am using jMeter.

I tried to test if the 500 users can get the page using http get and post requests and it worked. The problem now is how I can test posting the query and getting the results of it at the same time??

Could you please help me in that?

I appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here's what I got, and I am wondering if it is enough for testing submitting query and getting its result:
http://s28.postimg.org/pu83pev0t/6_4_2014_12_09_25_PM.png

Question: why the text:
POST data:
QueryTextBox=Ø§Ù?Ù?Ø¨Ù? Ù?Ø­Ù?Ø¯
is not readable?? Maybe because it is in Arabic? How I can make it readable

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds very straightforward. Where exactly is it that you're stuck?

Comment: @Ophir PrusaK I don't know if testing submitting the query then finding the response in jMeter is enough or not in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Without further info, it sounds like you might not have added a listener to your test plan that shows the server response.

Right click your HTTP sampler and add a "View Results Tree" listener to it.  That listener contains both the request and the response so you can view it.

How is the HTTP sampler configured, is the content encoding UTF-8?  I'm not sure what's populating the post data body.  In my own tests Arabic characters show up correctly.

Comment: Yes, I did and I saw the response, but is that enough??